# How do I only log just the host for a certain host?

Tags: nginx

I have the following to log just the referer's path:

```
map $http_referer $just_path {
  "~^(?P<path>[^?]*)(\?.*)?$" $path;
}
```

Basically, I don't want to log the referer's querystring. However, some requests come from ourselves, and for those I want to just log the `scheme + host` without the path (e.g. http://www.example.com).

How do I achieve that while still logging the `scheme + host + path` for everyone else? In short:

```
Site A: http://sitea.com/this/path?v=true -> http://sitea.com/this/path
Site B: https://siteb.com/another/path?another=query -> https://siteb.com/another/path
Our Site: https://www.example.com/this/other/path?x=true&v=false -> https://www.example.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are evaluated in order, so you can place a new line before the one you have to match your own host name.

For example:

```
map $http_referer $just_path {
    "~^(?<path>https?://www.example.com/)"  $path;
    "~^(?<path>[^?]*)"                      $path;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.